# KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/test-topic/partitions

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

While starting Kafka getting this following error.

```
KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/test-topic/partitions
```

Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Again and again, without showing us your configuration , it is impossible to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my answer, It is because of version mismatch of zookeeper and kafka.
Previously I was using kafka_2.8.0-0.8.0 with zookeeper 3.3.5
but then I installed kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1 with zookeeper 3.3.5 and now It's working fine.

Comment: how do u install a specific zookeeper version?

Comment: http://zookeeper.apache.org/releases.html#download
, you can find various release on this web page and installation steps are given at this link -> 

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Setting+Up+an+External+ZooKeeper+Ensemble

Answer (score 3):

Most likely this is because the topic is not created yet. Topic nodes in Zookeeper are created when broker processes the first message to the topic or, alternatively, when the AdminUtils.createTopic(...) call was made.